# Angular routes not refreshing the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to create an app with angular, and somehow the child state in not loading.

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url        : "/",
        templateUrl: "/admin/home/"
    })
    .state('users', {
        url        : "/users/",
        templateUrl: "/admin/users",
        controller : function ($stateParams) {
            console.log($stateParams);


            console.log("users");
        }
    })
    .state('users.new', {
        url        : "^/users/user/",
        templateUrl: "/admin/users/new",
        controller : function () {
            console.log("users.new");
        }
    })
    .state('users.user', {
        url        : "^/users/user/:uuid",
        templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {

            console.log($stateParams);

            return "/admin/users/" + $stateParams.uuid
        },
        controller : function () {
            console.log("users.user");
        }
    });
```

When I visiting the page

/users/user/55d8b1c706387b11480d60c1

I see the request to load the page, but only the "users" controller got executed.

This problem appears only with child states, switching between parent state working without problems.

I Using the latest versions of angular and ui-routes.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Please read this DOC](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

You mistake is in hierarchy. Child states use parent template as root and try find nested `<ui-view>`

You may add abstract state `user` without url, with empty template `<ui-view></ui-view>`, for nested viws. Then rename user, to E.G. `user.index`, it works for me

1st (It may works)

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url        : "/",
        templateUrl: "/admin/home/"
    })
    .state('users', {
        template: "<ui-view></ui-view>",
    })
    .state('users.index', {
        url        : "/users/",
        templateUrl: "/admin/users",
        controller : function ($stateParams) {
            console.log($stateParams);

        console.log("users");
    }
})
.state('users.new', {
    url        : "^/users/user/",
    templateUrl: "/admin/users/new",
    controller : function () {
        console.log("users.new");
    }
})
.state('users.user', {
    url        : "^/users/user/:uuid",
    templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {

        console.log($stateParams);

        return "/admin/users/" + $stateParams.uuid
    },
    controller : function () {
        console.log("users.user");
    }
});
```

2nd way is USE absulutly named views E.G.

```
views: { 
      "": { templateUrl: 'pages/menu.html' }, // relative noName view
      "header": { templateUrl: "pages/header.html"}, //relative named view
      "content@": { // Absolute name
           template: "<ui-view></ui-view>",
           controller: 'AuthController'}
    }
```